# Mac book pro 2014 stuck in base system

Tags: macbook-pro

I dropped my macbook off my recliner a few days ago. It fell about 2 feet & it has a hard case on it. I didn’t think much of it but when I tried using it the next morning I was getting the folder with a question mark in it during start up. I came on the forums, tried many different approaches and solutions that worked for everyone else did not work for me.

I can’t erase the macOS base system nor partition it: it doesn’t give me those options. I factory reset my computer about a month ago as well because I was having problems with Catalina. I don’t have anything backed up & that’s fine (I have flashdrives w/ my important files) & I have a flashdrive with Mojave on it but it is locked and I can’t figure it out.

When I hold down the option key at start up it prompts my install Mojave drive but no other drive. It of course won’t let me install Mojave but when I went back to DU there was a new image tried erasing & partitioning that & all I got were error messages. If anyone has any idea what to do please help. Un-mounting disks doesn’t work either.

[image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image][image]

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you are trying to have the installer erase itself.

Your internal storage is broken and not showing up, so you could install to an external drive or get a repair.  Both will work once it’s repaired and if you get your external drive erased, a clean install might let you run for a while or just know it needs someone that can diagnose and repair it.

Comment: How would I install to an external drive? Thank you btw!

Comment: Plug in a drive, run the installer, choose that drive to install. @JavierJasso in your image, there is one saying the drive is unlocked, that’s when you plug in an external drive and choose it.

Comment: I tried but when I get through the agreement stuff it says the disk is locked again.